# Executing SQL Stored Procedure with Output Parameter from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-4

Using EF, I'm trying to execute a stored procedure that returns a single string value, i.e. the status of an SQL Agent Job.

The stored procedure is declared as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[up_GetJobStatus](@JobStatus NVARCHAR(30) OUTPUT)
AS

-- some code omitted for brevity

SELECT @JobStatus = (
SELECT  
    CASE job_state 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Executing'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Waiting for thread'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Between retries'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Idle'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Suspended'
    WHEN 6 THEN '<unknown>'
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Performing completion actions'
END
FROM @xp_results results 
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
ON results.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE sj.job_id = @job_id)

RETURN
```

I have verified the stored procedure is working correct as I can execute it in query window and it returns

```
    @JobStatus
  ------------
  1|Idle
```

However when executing with EF, the param value is NULL

```
var param = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@JobStatus",
    DbType = DbType.String,
    Size = 30,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
};

var result = this.etlContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC dbo.up_GetJobStatus @JobStatus OUTPUT", param);
```

I've also tried the `ExecuteSqlCommand` method but that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried passing it using:
var result = this.etlContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC dbo.up_GetJobStatus {0}", param.Value)?;

Comment: tried it - didn't work

Comment: did you get any exceptions? or did it simply return null?

Comment: Have you had a look at this link (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896334(v=vs.100).aspx) on how to do it? you will first need to import the stored procedures into your dbmx

Answer (score 37):

1. Create stored procedure in database

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].myStoredProcName
       @inputParam1 VARCHAR(150),
       @inputParam2 VARCHAR(150),
       @myOutputParamBool BIT OUTPUT,
       @myOutputParamString VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT,
       @myOutputParamInt INT OUTPUT
   AS
   BEGIN
       -- sql here
   END
   ```
2. Update entity model from database to include stored procedure
   [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61Bf9.png)

3. Call the stored procedure from C# code

   ```
   // Type is System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter
   ObjectParameter myOutputParamBool = new ObjectParameter("myOutputParamBool", typeof(bool));
   ObjectParameter myOutputParamString = new ObjectParameter("myOutputParamString", typeof(string));
   ObjectParameter myOutputParamInt = new ObjectParameter("myOutputParamInt", typeof(Int32));

   using (var context = new SandCryptEntities())
   {
       context.myStoredProcName(inputParam1, inputParam2, myOutputParamBool, myOutputParamString, myOutputParamInt);   
   }

   bool myBool = Convert.ToBoolean(myOutputParamBool.Value);
   string myString = Convert.ToString(myOutputParamString.Value);
   int myInt = Convert.ToInt32(myOutputParamInt.Value);
   ```

Comment: I do have Table Types as my params to SP, so They didn't come as param in sp if I follow your way, please suggest

Answer (score 4):

Here's an actual answer.  Apparently there are serious issues with output parameters in entity framework when you're using DbContext/code first.  This article has a good discussion and workaround: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-entity-framework-code-first-with-stored-procedures-that-have-output-parameters.  Apparently it's supposed to be "fixed" with an update, but I haven't really seen that happen.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following code. It is working for me.

```
var param = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "@JobStatus",
    DbType = DbType.String,
    Size = 30,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
};

var result = this.etlContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("EXEC dbo.up_GetJobStatus @JobStatus=@JobStatus OUTPUT", param);
string JobStatus = param.Value.ToString();
```

The first @JobStatus is your param ParameterName and the second @JobStatus is the PROCEDURE Parameter name.

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on vicky's answer.

```
var localPar = new SqlParameter("@userlogin", ad);
var Paramater2 = new SqlParameter("@Paramater2", "");
Paramater2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
Paramater2.Size = 30;
Paramater2.DbType = DbType.String;

var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
parameters.Add(localPar);
parameters.Add(Paramater2);


var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<object>("EXEC dbo.uspSP @userlogin, @Paramater2 =@Paramater2 OUTPUT", parameters.ToArray());

var x = result.FirstOrDefault();

return Paramater2.Value.ToString();
```

If you have more than 1 parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Just need a slight change.

First Building Your Query-

```
var query=@"$Declare @return_Value nvarchar(30) @JobStatus nvarchar(30)
EXEC @return_Value=up_GetJobStatus @JobStatus=@JobStatus
SELECT @JobStatus as N'@JobStatus'";
```

Secondly, using SqlQueryRaw.

```
var result = this.etlContext.Database.SqlQueryRaw<string> 
("query").AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault();
```

result should have the value you are looking for.