# Entity Framework 6 ObjectParameter is Null After Execution of a Stored Procedure With Output Param

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So, I'm trying to execute a SP from Entity Framework 6 and return the output parameter @AffectedRowCount that holds the number of rows that were affected by the execution. Below is my code and a screenshot of the SSMS execution showing the correct result. rowCount.Value is null everytime it executes through C# even after I reset the data. Any thoughts.

```
    public int UpdateStagingTable()
    {
        var rowCount = new ObjectParameter("AffectedRowCount", typeof(Int32));
        be.sp_LoanCategoryMonitor(rowCount);
        return Convert.ToInt32(rowCount.Value);
    }
```

This is the autogened Code from the dbContext

```
public virtual ObjectResult<sp_LoanCategoryMonitor_Result> sp_LoanCategoryMonitor(ObjectParameter affectedRowCount)
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<sp_LoanCategoryMonitor_Result>("sp_LoanCategoryMonitor", affectedRowCount);
    }
```

SSMS Execution

```
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @AffectedRowCount int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_LoanCategoryMonitor]
        @AffectedRowCount = @AffectedRowCount OUTPUT

SELECT  @AffectedRowCount as N'@AffectedRowCount'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

SSMS Results

[image]

[image]

Comment: this discussion might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068027/executing-sql-stored-procedure-with-output-parameter-from-entity-framework

Comment: @twinmind, thanks. I already worked through that post prior to posting this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The developer who created the SP for whatever reason added a select statement in the last statement in the SP. This was interfering with the output parameter. I updated the SP then cleaned my .edmx file of the SP and then added it back. I ran it and it ran as expected.

[image]