# Retrieve Output parameters from stored procedure using entity framework/MVC

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameters, output

After hours upon hours of research, I can't retrieve the output parameter from the stored procedure through entity, or a helpful link about the issue. All solutions and suggested practices I have come across don't work or if they do work, they are missing enough detail so their solution can be done correctly. Any help would be appreciated, especially detailed help. Thank you.

Example of approaches that don't work:

```
ObjectParameter Output = new ObjectParameter("ID", typeof(Int32)); 
context.InsertPerson(Name, Description, Output);
```

this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-entity-framework-code-first-with-stored-procedures-that-have-output-parameters) has a solution that I have not tried because it is a bit beyond my knowledge and a bit too invasive, and doesn't really use entity framework in the end.

Comment: Add stored procedure code, more code of C# that you write

Comment: Some of your code should help us help you, but in the meantime, [did you try this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41488387/10558242)

Comment: @FelipeMartins Yes, I Have tried exactly that, it does not work. However after seeing your link I had a light bulb moment and figured out that I forgot to update the entity model and instead wrote the code i need, which doesn;t work obviously. thank you a lot for your help guys.